# Two routes in laravel getting confused, I need a solution to this

Tags: laravel-5, routes

```
 1. Route::get('/admin', [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@admin',
        'as' => 'admin' ]);



   2. Route::get('/{uri}', [
        'uses' => 'ArticleController@article',
        'as' => 'article' ]);
```

if I try to go to admin route it goes to article route, I need a solution for both routes to work.

Answer (score 0):

**The conflict arrives in your case due to `/{uri}` matches to `/admin` ,**

For example. `/xyz`, `/abc` and even `/admin` match to `/{uri}` route.

**You can do something like this to avoid it.**

```
Route::get('/admin', [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@admin', 'as' => 'admin' ]);

Route::get('/uri/{uri}', [ 'uses' => 'ArticleController@article', 'as' => 'article' ]);
```

Note that now `/admin` will match to your `/admin route` and `/uri/{parameter}` will match to your `/uri/{uri} route`

Answer (score 0):

**You have to write route 1 first then route 2**

Follow: [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/route-parameter-where-using-not)